# How to create new column based on key dictionary inside list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I have a data frame with list of dictionary (with unequal length) and i want to create a new column based on key dictionary and dictionary value as a column value

> criteria
> 0     [{'Seniority level': 'Entry level'}, {'Employm...
> 1                    [{'Employment type': 'Full-time'}]
> 2     [{'Seniority level': 'Associate'}, {'Employmen...
> 3                    [{'Employment type': 'Part-time'}]
> 4     [{'Seniority level': 'Mid-Senior level'}, {'Em...
>
> > ...                                                 ...
> > 2768  [{'Seniority level': 'Entry level'}, {'Employm...
> > 2769  [{'Seniority level': 'Entry level'}, {'Employm...
> > 2770  [{'Seniority level': 'Entry level'}, {'Employm...
> > 2771  [{'Seniority level': 'Mid-Senior level'}, {'Em...
> > 2772  [{'Seniority level': 'Entry level'}, {'Employm...

[I want to create the new column like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBxqP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have a function that does something along those lines:

```
import pandas as pd 

def reformat_json_column(dataframe: pd.DataFrame, column_name: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Split a list of JSON data with one line per element of the JSON
    Each key of the JSON data is then used to construct a column and store the
    related data
    """
    data = dataframe.explode(column_name).reset_index(drop=True)
    data = pd.concat(
        [
            data.drop(column_name, axis=1),
            pd.json_normalize(data[column_name]),  # type: ignore
        ],
        axis=1,
    )
    return data
```

Here is a working example:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1, 2, 3],
        "b": [
            [{"c": 4, "d": 5}],
            [{"c": 6, "d": 7}],
            [{"c": 8, "d": 9}, {"c": 10, "d": 11}],
        ],
    }
)

assert_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"a": [1, 2, 3, 3], "c": [4, 6, 8, 10], "d": [5, 7, 9, 11]}
)
pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(reformat_json_column(test_df, "b"), assert_df)
```